# How to run Cypress tests with GitHub Actions

Tags: reactjs, typescript, cypress

I want to GitHub Actions to automatically run the cypress tests but after 40 minutes of running the tests are failing and I can not identify what is going.

```
name: Cypress Tests

on:
  workflow_dispatch:
  # The cron is set on UTC Time
  schedule:
    - cron: '0 15 * * *'

jobs:
  cypress-run:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Setup Node
        uses: actions/setup-node@v3
        with:
          node-version-file: '.node-version'
      # Install NPM dependencies, cache them correctly
      - name: Yarn install
        run: yarn install
      # Get information date to put on the report file name
      - name: Get current date
        id: date
        run: echo "::set-output name=date::$(date +'%Y-%m-%d')"
      # Run Cypress Test
      - name: Cypress run
        id: cypress
        continue-on-error: true
        uses: cypress-io/github-action@v4
        with:
          build: yarn build
          start: yarn start:staging
      # Combine all the report in one file
      - name: Combine Cypress reports
        run: yarn mochawesome-merge ./cypress/reports/mochawesome-reports/*.json -o ./cypress/reports/combined-report-${{ steps.date.outputs.date }}.json
      # Convert the report to HTML Format
      - name: Generate HTML from JSON report
        run: yarn marge ./cypress/reports/combined-report-${{ steps.date.outputs.date }}.json --reportDir ./cypress/reports --inline
      # Upload file on the Github Action Job Summary
      - name: Upload file
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v3
        with:
          name: 'Cypress-Test-Report-${{ steps.date.outputs.date }}'
          path: /home/runner/work/frontend/frontend/cypress/reports/combined-report-${{ steps.date.outputs.date }}.html
      # Get test failure information to send on Slack channel
      - name: Get test failure information from Cypress report
        id: set_var
        run: |
          content=`cat /home/runner/work/frontend/frontend/cypress/reports/combined-report-${{ steps.date.outputs.date }}.json`
          content="${content//'%'/'%25'}"
          content="${content//$'\n'/'%0A'}"
          content="${content//$'\r'/'%0D'}"
          echo "::set-output name=packageJson::$content"
      # Send Cypress test information to Slack channel
      - name: Send GitHub Action trigger data to Slack
        id: slack
        uses: slackapi/slack-github-action@v1.22.0
        with:
          channel-id: '#1_bug_reporting'
          payload: |
            {
              "text": "Cypress Tests date: ${{ steps.date.outputs.date }}\nCypress Tests finished with ${{fromJson(steps.set_var.outputs.packageJson).stats.failures}} Failed\nSee results at: https://github.com/${{ github.repository }}/actions/runs/${{ github.run_id }}",
              "blocks": [
                {
                  "type": "section",
                  "text": {
                    "type": "mrkdwn",
                    "text": "Cypress Tests date: ${{ steps.date.outputs.date }}\nCypress Tests finished with ${{fromJson(steps.set_var.outputs.packageJson).stats.failures}} Failed\nSee results at: https://github.com/${{ github.repository }}/actions/runs/${{ github.run_id }}"
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
        env:
          SLACK_BOT_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.SLACK_BOT_TOKEN }}
```

The failing message on most of them is

```
AssertionError: Timed out retrying after 4000ms: expected '/login' to equal '/orgs/dev-e2e-advanced'
    at Context.eval (http://localhost:3000/__cypress/tests?p=cypress/support/e2e.ts:118:29)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can start with basis:

Your Yaml File:

```
name: End-to-end tests
on: [push]
jobs:
  cypress-run:
    runs-on: ubuntu-20.04
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
      # Install NPM dependencies, cache them correctly
      # and run all Cypress tests
      - name: Cypress run
        uses: cypress-io/github-action@v4
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment 
I'm trying to find why my code is not working even though it’s very clear so why do you think this one will work and why the current one is not working ?

Comment: The reason is there's an issue with your cy.visit() command. The page is not being loaded before the test that's why.

Solutions is : Please update the default command timeout in cypress.config.js file using below line:

defaultCommandTimeout: 10000

Instead of 10000 you can use any value of time in milliseconds. Using this your, timeout issue will be resolved.

Comment: If you have cypress dashboard, you would be able to see the video of the issue. If not, then you'll may have to read into the logs of the CI run and see what may be the issue. Also, don't just up the commandTimeout unless it is a last resort.

Comment: @1harshh Thank you for your answer here the problem is my cypress tests are working perfectly on the localhost but when i am using the GitHub workflow all the tests are failing. And i tried the     defaultCommandTimeout: 10000
it didn't solve the problem.